# iOS updates getting listed slowly

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, ios-appstore

When I check for updates on an iOS device of mine, the results takes quite a bit of time to **get listed**. And even sometimes they don't and I've to restart the app by killing it. Although the speed when downloading something from the App Store(whether it be a new app or an update) or any other Apple store is pretty good. It's **just** the updates trying to get listed that takes quite a bit of time.

This problem isn't just tied to me as well. It happens in other devices that belong to my other family members whom I use the same store account for purchases.

In my opinion, this isn't a network problem as well because everything other than trying to get the updates listed is pretty fast.

I would have said this is because I live in Turkey and I'm in the USA App Store with the help of store credits but then again everything other than trying to get the  updates listed is pretty fast!

Also our Mac updates show up pretty quickly.

So what do you think might be the problem?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that this is an issue with your network or your device. I have the same behavior on all my 5 iOS devices and so does everybody else I talked about this topic.

I guess the slowness comes from within Apple's datacenter(s). Checking for updates is a "bigger" process I guess (checking your apps, asking the database, etc.) than "just" downloading, which is pretty simple (establishing a connection, download the data). I just guess that checking for updates just needs some more web service requests than downloading. And since this is done by millions of users, the queue may take a while until your request is processed.

So my **answer** is: *I think you can do nothing about it*.

Comment: Oh crap. That's what I was afraid of. Although nice explanation man, makes sense. Thanks, hopefully Apple comes up with fix quick.